# How to save all files/links from a telegram chat/channel?

Tags: download-manager, web-crawler, bulk, telegram-messenger

I want to save ALL http(s) links and/or files, posted to some telegram chat (private or group) or channel (like mailing list).

I need an analog of `TumblOne` (for tumblr) `VkOpt` (able to save chating history in vk.com ) or `jDownloader` (for file hostings) - the program, which will parce all chating history from the start to the current state, find all web links, save them to a txt file, find all attached files (archives, ebooks, music, video, txt files, photos, etc) and download them to selected folder (direct download, not from TG cache, I need all files, even I don't save it manually, and all links, even I don't read or delete posts with them).

I tried to use some universal download managers (`JDownloader, USDownloader, Tucan`), but all of them don't support telegram. Maybe, there are some offline apps for this purpose or any crawlers for browser version of TG?

I found the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/994896/642513) suggesting to use of [php cli telegram client](https://github.com/zyberspace/php-telegram-cli-client) script, but this work doesn't support by the author anymore. Is there are supporting, developed analogs? I didn't find them on [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net).

Some clients for TG (at least, for windows), as far as I know, support automanically preload media and messages, maybe, is it possible to run to the start of dialog, wait some time (to load all files) and then select and save all messages and try to get files from TG cache (if there are not any other variants)?

I publish my question here, not on the SoftwareRecomendations, not only because there is a higher probability of receiving a useful answer, but also because, as far as I know, there is not a ready-to-use product for my purpose, but perhaps there is some intermediate solution, such as a custom framework or php library.

Answer (score 34):

You can do it from [Telegram Desktop](https://desktop.telegram.org/).

Install it (you have a portable version for Windows if you prefer it) and log in to your account.

You will see your chats and channels. Enter the desired channel. You can do this even if the other person deleted the account (the channel's name will be "Deleted Account").

Expand the three-dot menu to the right and click "Export chat history".

It'll appear a box asking some parameters. Choose what you need:

[image: "Export chat history" menu]

Note: There is a 1.5GB limit per file. If any of your files are bigger than that, download them individually. But there is no size limit as to how much data can be downloaded in total. You can download all the files from the chat.

You'll end up with a folder structure like this:

[image: Saved Telegram chat folder structure]

You will be able then to read your old chat anytime with any web browser, just opening "messages.html".